# SQL Delete with join 4

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried this request :

```
DELETE FROM user_tools AS UT
LEFT OUTER JOIN tools AS T ON UT.tool_id = T.id
WHERE UT.user_id = :user_id AND T.category = :category";
```

My goal is to delete records from a table with a condition from a join in an other one. I try several solution without success. Can you help ?

(I use PDO, it's why i have : in my where clause, but it's the same with values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify from which tables to delete in a join. You do that right after the keyword `delete`

```
DELETE UT
FROM user_tools AS UT
LEFT OUTER JOIN tools AS T ON UT.tool_id = T.id
WHERE UT.user_id = :user_id 
AND T.category = :category";
```

By the way your condition `T.category = :category` turns your `left join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried this but i had tried probably with an other error !